# What is the purpose of the xorg.conf file on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, 15.04

What is the purpose of the xorg.conf file located in /etc/X11/ on Ubuntu 15.04? It doesn't seem to do anything, and appears to be overwritten on each boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is created when you run `sudo nvidia-xconfig` and is loaded when the host is booting up.  It is not created or updated each and every time your system reboots.  It is used for configuring the X.Org Server.  More info at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorg.conf

With my current configuration with my NVIDIA 8800GT and my older 17 inch monitor, I still need the xorg.conf file to create the modes supported by my monitor so that the `XRandR` is capable of controlling that monitor.